# Is there a Logback summariser?

Tags: java, logback

Is there a summariser for java Logback that instead of repeating messages prints out "last message repeated 5000 times"?

I'm printing out the same database connection error 10 times a millisecond but have no control over the connection pool (quartz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-803 at least, not a standard one. Since you're not the first one to want such, you might be able to find one from some other codebase. Happy hunting.